# Shapefile not working in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am a beginner with QGIS. I downloaded from different websites administrative levels for a country (0, 1, 2), full package: dbf, shp, shp.xlm, snb, shx, sbx, sbn, prj etc. However, QGIS is not opening the shapefiles (see picture attached)

[image]

Actually, only the KMZ files are working.

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: export each kmz to shapefile to be able to edit.

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. This error usually comes up, when you try loading a shape-file without the necessary additional files. Have you unzipped all files, or only the ones with the .shp-extension? Also, you may save the .kmz as .shp and work with these.

Comment: You seem to try to open a temporary file, are you sure it still exist ?

Comment: shapefile must die! :) http://switchfromshapefile.org/

Comment: Please include a link to the shapefiles that don't work so we can test them.